# Swift looping through array

Tags: ios, swift, loops, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that has 100 cells. I want to create an array that will hold index values of that table that I want to disable the table cells if the table row selected matches any of the values in the array.

I have found that the following code works to disable a specific cell that I give it.

```
UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

This is how I am checking which cell is selected:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


            let selectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
            let workoutSelected = selectedRow
            stringPassedTableView = workoutSelected!

            let myVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "showWorkout") as! WorkoutViewController
            myVC.stringPassed = stringPassedTableView
            navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true)


    }
```

Comment: I should also note that I found that I can accomplish this by giving it a value:

if(indexPath.row == 2)
{
UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
}

Comment: So if you need to disable cells in row 0, 5, 13, 67 then you need an array that contains 0, 5, 13, 67?

Comment: Joakim - correct

Comment: Don't use an array containing index paths. Add the `selected` or `enabled` information to your data model. The  benefit is that the Ui will be reliably updated in `cellForRow`.

Comment: Then what is the problem?

Comment: The array will always be changing, so when a cell is selected by the user, it needs to look into that array, and if the selected row index matches any of the array values, then disable that cell and don't do anything.

Comment: Why do you call `indexPathForSelectedRow`? That's pointless. The method gives you the index path in the `indexPath` parameter.

Comment: You should probably use a `Set<IndexPath>` rather than an array.  Then you can simply use `contains`

Comment: @Paulw11 You can use `contains` with an `Array` as well.

Comment: You can, but it is less efficient. It may not matter for small arrays, but it does for larger ones and if you are going to create something to store the selected rows, you might as well use the correct something.  Not only is `contains` more efficient on a set, so is removal as there is no need to compact the data like there is with an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following tableview delegate method to allow selection or not

```
tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

Simply check if the cell index is in your disabled cell indexes and if so return nil. Otherwise return the indexpath.

You can see the documentation here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614943-tableview?language=objc#return-value

Answer (score 0):

A much better way that, create an array of your model class which data you are passing into tableView data source.

Add a property into model class like named as "isSelectable" and assign it properly when you are parsing your model class data.

Use this "isSelectable" property, when you will select a row then check this property it is true or false and performs operation accordingly.

Hope you understand !!

Answer (score 0):

You have an array (or set) as a class property

```
var disabledRows = [IndexPaath]()
```

then simply use it at the start of the func

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if disabledRows.contains(indexPath) { return }

    // code to handle row with enabled cell
}
```